# ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-workbench, workbench

I got this error "ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)" with all my table with constraints on foreign keys.

```
Executing SQL script in server    
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'shop_online.t_newsletters' (errno: 150)
```

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_newsletters` (
  `id_newsletter` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,   
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `content` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `author` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `creation` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_newsletter`, `author`) ,  
  INDEX `fk_t_newsletters_t_administrators1` (`author` ASC) ,  
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_newsletters_t_administrators1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`author` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (`id_administrator` ) 
    ON DELETE SET NULL 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci
```

resulted in:

```
   
SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed
```

I'm working with MySQL Workbench and this is the model : http://puu.sh/42CTd.png.

I am trying that because I don't want to lose any of the entries on my DB if I delete a user.

If you have another solution, I'm ready to try it!

EDIT : All the database

```
 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_newsletters` (
  `id_newsletter` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `content` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `author` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `creation` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_newsletter`, `author`) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_newsletters_t_administrators1` (`author` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_newsletters_t_administrators1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`author` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (`id_administrator` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_daily_tips` (
`id_daily_tip` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`title` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `content` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `author` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_daily_tip`, `author`) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_daily_tips_t_administrators1` (`author` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_daily_tips_t_administrators1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`author` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (`id_administrator` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_news` (
  `id_news` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `introduction` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `content` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `author` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `creation` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `modification` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `modificator` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_news`, `modificator`, `author`) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_news_t_administrators1` (`author` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_news_t_administrators2` (`modificator` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_news_t_administrators1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`author` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (`id_administrator` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_news_t_administrators2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`modificator` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (`id_administrator` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_magazines` (
  `id_magazine` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `file` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `view` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `author` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_magazine`, `author`) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_magazines_t_administrators1` (`author` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_magazines_t_administrators1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`author` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (`id_administrator` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_members` (
  `id_member` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `email` VARCHAR(326) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `nickname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `title` ENUM('M','Mme','Mlle','Dr','Me') NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `postal_code` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `country` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_member`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_categories` (
  `id_category` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_category`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_sub_categories` (
  `id_sub_category` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `category` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sub_category`, `category`) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_sub_categories_t_categories1` (`category` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_sub_categories_t_categories1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_categories` (`id_category` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_articles` (
 `id_article` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `price` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `stock` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `informations` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `author` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `creation` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `subcategory` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_article`, `author`, `subcategory`) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_articles_t_administrators` (`author` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_t_articles_t_sub_categories1` (`subcategory` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_articles_t_administrators`
    FOREIGN KEY (`author` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (`id_administrator` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_articles_t_sub_categories1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory` )
    REFERENCES `shop_online`.`t_sub_categories` (`id_sub_category` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_online`.`t_administrators` (
```

`id_administrator` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

`name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

`email` VARCHAR(326) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

`login` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

`password` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

`last_connection` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`id_administrator`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got `author` as part of your primary key, which means it's not nullable, but you've got `ON DELETE SET NULL` on the foreign key constraint on that field. These two conditions are incompatible.

To fix it, remove `author` from your `PRIMARY KEY` declaration; your `id_newsletter` field is already an `auto_increment` so should be unique unless your application sets it specifically (in which case you shouldn't use `auto_increment`).

It's a good idea to verify that the referenced field is indexed and has a compatible data type too; I can't see that from the provided information, but it's a good thing to add to your "errno 150 checklist" :)

Comment: Oh, too obvious error for me x)

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as correct!

Comment: I changed it but still don't work :/

I posted all the database up here!

Comment: Does the `t_administrators` table exist? it's not in this output.

Comment: She is, already synchronized.

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `t_administrators`?

Comment: I added it at the end

Comment: I'll do it on every table!

I need more practice with that, I don't usually use something else than CASCADE :/

Thank you again!